# TCPDF no footer on page if condition is met?

Tags: footer, tcpdf

I am trying to set a conditional statement where a footer is set or not.

```
    if($data['voucher']===0){
        $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
        $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetXY(0, 10);

        $pdf->create_invoice();
    }
    //CUSTOM CONTENT
    //END 
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(true);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(true);
```

But the footer is still set. However if I set

```
$pdf->setPrintHeader(true);
```

the header is set but footer doesn't react.

The `Header()` and the `Footer()` functions - are defined in an extended class.

Comment: Both `setPrintHeader()` and `setPrintFooter()` functions are document-wide, not per-page properties if you try to set headers' and footers' displays per-page.

Comment: Does a per page footer exists? and it looks like setPrintHeader(false) works with a custom header created in $pdf->create_invoice and have the doc wide header for othe pages

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520446/tcpdf-having-footer-header-on-certain-pages-only has tips for your question. You must check conditions in your `Header()` and `Footer()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers and footers aren't printed until the page is ended, which is normally called when you add a new page with Addpage(); So you should end the page manually and then turn headers/footers back on.

```
 if($data['voucher']===0){

            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
            $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
            $pdf->SetXY(0, 10);

            $pdf->create_invoice();


            $pdf->Endpage();  //END THE PAGE AND TURN HEADERS/FOOTERS BACK ON
            $pdf->setPrintHeader(true);
            $pdf->setPrintFooter(true);
        }
        //CUSTOM CONTENT
        //END 
        $pdf->Addpage(); // Any new page created now will again have headers footers
```

Comment: Wow, olger it looks your answer is exactly what i am trying to accomplish (still need to check some other conditional statements, but this really looks like it)

Comment: Great! TCPDF (in my opinion) has a weird order of doing things in some cases so I'm not surprised there's some confusion